# JavaScript Check for palindrome (spaces & punctuation included)

Tags: javascript, regex, function, palindrome

Trying to check for palindromes. I've checked other answers but none included punctuation & spaces.

"never odd or even" and "A man, a plan, a canal. Panama" Should return true but they don't.

```
   function palindrome(str) {
  if(str.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase() === str.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join("")){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
palindrome("eye");
```

Comment: They shouldn't return true if spaces and punctuation are part of the palindrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an error in your RegEx. If you want to remove the spaces, you don't need that `\s`. Try changing:

```
str.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "")
```

With

```
str.replace(/[^\w]|_/g, "")
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. New to js why does it work without \s? (will accept answer in 5 mins)

Comment: Well, with that regular expression you are saying: replace underscores and everything that is not a `\w` (a word character) or a `\s` (a whitespace) with an empty string. That means that spaces are not removed. Actually, I have to say that the one proposed by leo.fcx is certainly cleaner.

Comment: @Aioros: Your regex works with `0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0` because the `_` and `-` are removed, but leo's regex does not remove `_` because `\W` does not match them. So, for OP, your answer is working. You may use `/\W|_/g` regex in your answer.

Comment: Right, didn't think about that. The \W is still nicer than ^\w, though :)

Answer (score 2):

Use instead:

```
str.replace(/\W/g, "")
```

Which will replace any non-word char by empty string.

Comment: Worth to mention: `\W = [^\w] = [^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Didn't work for "0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0". Thanks for trying though.

Comment: To make it clearer: the ``\`` in the string must be doubled to denote a literal ``\``, but it does not seem working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a simpler regex which simply replaces any character that is not in the alphabet?

```
function palindrome(str) {
  if(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").toLowerCase() === str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join("")){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the above but reformatted:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    let regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    return str.replace(regex, '').toLowerCase() === str.replace(regex, '').toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with unevenly spaced numbers in a string, punctuation and uppercase letters, you can use

> 

```
let regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
  return (
    str.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase() ===
    str.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join("")
  );
```